# Eclipse hangs when importing Android NDK project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm using a fresh copy of the Eclipse ADT 23.0.2 package (this happens with older versions aswell). When I create a new workspace and try to import an Android project that uses the NDK, Eclipse hangs on the "Import Projects" dialog. Trying to close the dialog pops up the message

```
"Wizard can not be closed due to an active operation. You must cancel the operation before you can close the wizard".
```

The only thing I can do is kill the javaw.exe process, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons this happens is that when you set the location of the SDK and NDK in Eclipse, the location of the NDK gets stored within the workspace itself. You can verify this by creating a new workspace and navigating to

```
Windows->Preferences->Android
```

"SDK Location" should be set but when you click on the "NDK" option, the location should be empty. Setting the NDK location again and then importing a project into your freshly created workspace should solve the problem.

The exact location of the save file is:

```
*workspace*/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.prefs
```